# Rails, rendering a collection

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have to render a collection of orders like this:

```
= render partial: 'order_row', collection: @order_items, as: order_item
```

In my partial I would have to use `order_item.product` multiple times. Is there a way to say that product is `order_item.product`? I tried with `locals: {product: order_item.product}` but it looks like the `order_item` can be used only in the rendered partial. In other words, how to translate this `.each` do block to a render.

```
  - @order_items.each do |order_item|
    = render 'order_row', product: order_item.product, order_item: order_item
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside a partial you can still assign variables:

```
= render partial: 'order_row', collection: @order_items, as: :order_item
```

In partial:

```
- product = order_item.product
%p Then goes your partial
```

Comment: I am marking this as correct because probably there is no way to do it the way I wanted :)

Answer (score 0):

you might map your collection before rendering, like:

```
= render partial: 'order_row', collection: @order_items.map(&:product), as: order_item
```